# I am getting net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200 (ok) for image response in C

Tags: c, google-chrome, http, networking

I am building simple HTTP server that sends request for the image, however getting `net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200` in console and image is not shown

I have this code that reads bytes and when I print it, it is correct with the image size that is shown from image_info of OS:

```
    FILE* file = fopen(full_fpath, "rb");
    if (file == NULL) {
        char* response = build_response("404", NULL, NULL,0, now);
        send_response(sd, response);
        return NULL;
    }
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long int file_size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    unsigned char* file_content = (unsigned char*)malloc(file_size * sizeof(unsigned char));
    size_t bytes_read = fread(file_content, sizeof(unsigned char), file_size, file);
    printf("%zu\n", bytes_read);
    fclose(file);

  
    char* response = build_response("200", f_type, (char*)file_content,bytes_read, now);
    send_response(sd, response);
```

And here is the response part:

```
char* build_response(char* status, char* type, char* file, size_t file_size, struct tm* now) {
    char* response = malloc(50000);
    bzero(response, sizeof(response));

    char length[50];
    if(file_size > 0) {
        sprintf(length, "%zu", file_size);
    }

    // file not found
    if(strcmp(status, "404") == 0) {
       // some code
    }
    // ok response
    else {
        strcpy(response, OK_RESPONSE);
        strcat(response, TYPE);
        strcat(response, type);
        strcat(response, "\r\n");
        strcat(response, LEN);
        strcat(response, length);
        printf(length);
        printf("\n");
        strcat(response, "\r\n\r\n");
        strcat(response, file);
    }
    return response;
}
```

I checked TYPE and it is correct. This code works with `index.html`, `style.css` that I am requesting, but not image.

Comment: `malloc(50000)` can cause memory leaks.

Comment: @is_this_theory – 
An _image_ is not a string.